# How can I lock screen on lxde

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

Like gnome Control + alt + L

In Lxde how can i do that? What I have to intall to do this?

thanks

**--searching for a solution on my own but...**

ok if I do **alt+f2** and type **xscreensaver-command -lock** that's a small solution. tryed to do 
an small script but it's not working..

this is what I do

vi lock.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
xscreensaver-command -lock
exit 0
```

chmod +x lock.sh

but this doesnt work.. ideas?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You should be able to bind the screensaver lock command to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> by editing your Lubuntu keyboard & mouse configuration file

Add the following to `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`

```
<keybind key="C-A-L">      
  <action name="Execute">        
    <command>xscreensaver-command -lock</command>      
  </action>    
</keybind>
```

This should be located inbetween the XML tags

```
<keyboard>
...
</keyboard
```

[image]

Logout and login for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Type `openbox --reconfigure` in terminal for changes to take effect. This is _GNU/Linux_ we're talking about—logout/login is superfluous.

Comment: Be careful not to use `$HOME`=`/root` for your `rc` file, but your real user.

Comment: @Richard, or `openbox --restart` to get it done.

Comment: Place this between the `</keyboard>` -- that's really important tip. Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

I would elaborate/combine some of the answers. First (in a terminal) start your editor:

```
vi ~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml
```

Then search for the mentioned faulty code:

```
<keybind key="C-A-L">      
  <action name="Execute">        
    <command>xscreensaver-command -lock</command>      
  </action>    
</keybind>
```

and change it to use the dm-tool:

```
<keybind key="C-A-L">      
  <action name="Execute">        
    <command>dm-tool lock</command>      
  </action>    
</keybind>
```

Then add a section, so the Windows+L combination works too:

```
<keybind key="W-L">
  <action name="Execute">        
    <command>dm-tool lock</command>      
  </action>    
</keybind>
```

Finally, finish the editor (saving the file) and activate it:

```
openbox --reconfigure
```

Good luck and thanks for all the answers found here...

Comment: this should be the answer

Comment: I already had dm-tool installed by default. I would have had to install xscreensaver for the accepted answer to work. -Thanks

Answer (score 9):

We can also use "lxlock" command that's provided by the lxde. 
I just found it on Ubuntu 14.04. 
We can add the below lines in our openbox config file in the keyboard.  `vim $HOME/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`

```
<!-- keybinding for Screen Lock-->
    <keybind key="W-L">
        <action name="Execute">
          <command>lxlock</command>
        </action>
```

And then restart the openbox with the following command.

`openbox --restart`

This will enable locking of the desktop by hitting Windows Key + L

Comment: To clarify for readers: `lxlock` is installed in `/usr/bin` as a shell script that tries to identify/invoke various common screensaver/lock options that might coexist on the system. If if it doesn't find any other options, it will fallback to `xscreensaver-command -lock` anyway. Personally I find it easier and more (hypothetically) cross-platform to go straight to X, and a screen lock really isn't somewhere that I care about eye-candy!

Comment: confirmed for Lubuntu Trusty

Comment: Using `lxlock` solves the problem in Lubuntu 14.04.03 LTS

Answer (score 3):

1. I'm not good at scripts but I would do it like this (and it should work):
   lock.sh contents:

   ```
   xscreensaver-command -lock
   ```

   In terminal:

   ```
   sh ./lock.sh
   ```
2. Better way is to create a .desktop file (which you can place on panel inside of "Application launch bar" applet, and it will be in main menu all the time).
   In `/usr/share/applications` create file `lock.desktop` and it should contain:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]   
   Type=Application   
   Icon={path to icon you like}   
   Name={what would you like to name it}   
   Categories=Utility; {this will place it in Accessories menu in your main menu}  
   Exec=xscreensaver-command -lock  
   NoDisplay=false {if you set this to true you will not see it in menu and while adding to panel}
   ```

Save it and it should appear in menu (maybe after few seconds)

Comment: you're welcome. If you run into any troubles with this, write here, will help as much as I can

Comment: About the keybinding (sorry, can't commit on others' answers):  you should just copy the text which fossfreedom posted in that place, it's not there yet.