# Not every feature supported in lubuntu interface

Tags: unity, 14.04, lubuntu, lxde

I've been using LXDE for a month and newly I've realised that not every option included in LXDE interface. 
for example, when I start ubuntu with default unity interface, everything is normal. but when I open with a lighter interface which is LXDE, for example, I can't find "startup windows" tool anywhere! or I could not find "shortcuts for keyboard" . or I could not find any "screen lock" options. I found something like a screensaver but it does not include everything I need.

So I must ask that is there anything I missed about downloading this lighter interface? 
should I download more stuff to be able to use every general ubuntu software and tools?
if so, what are they?

Answer (score 0):

Well LXDE is very lightweight, to add start-up applications you put a .desktop file in the `~/.config/autostart` folder. See this non GUI section from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/48327/186134).

Advanced users may want to put a `.desktop file` in `~/.config/autostart` to run applications after a user login. This may have following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=<Name of application as displayed>
Exec=<command to execute>
Icon=<full path to icon>
Comment=<optinal comments>
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

To set-up locking settings, you go to "Start" -> Preferences -> Light Locker.

And to add short cuts, you simply edit this file: `/home/<user>/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml`. I got that from [this](http://forum.lxde.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=457) and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1422861) forum.

Answer (score -1):

As lxde is an **light weight Desktop edition**, might all the feature is **disabled by default to boost desktop performance**, as i am not a user of lxde but you can look at this guide
to install **complete lxde** http://www.howtogeek.com/107368/how-to-install-the-lightweight-lxde-desktop-on-ubuntu/

And if you are want lock screen feauture on your desktop edition you can take this question - [How can I lock screen on lxde](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80145/how-can-i-lock-screen-on-lxde)

Comment: This link doesn't answer his question, it is simply an installation guide.

Comment: it is refrence of ... complete lxde installation... i just wanted to help you ...

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but there is no point adding a link that doesn't actually **answer** the question - even if it is helpful.